# relative import of modules in pytest in a Scafold structure

Tags: python, import, module, pytest

using pyscafold in order to build a module I get an structure as follows

```
scr    
---module    
------__init__.py    
------file.py (containing func inside)    
tests   
---fileTest.py
```

How is the right way to import file.py in the test file fileTest.py?

So far many of this variations dont work:

```
import pytest
from ../src/module import func
```

including this in **init**.py does not help:

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
```

These do not help:

```
from .src/module/myfile import func
from ..src/module/myfile import func
```

Answer (score 0):

There should not be forward slashes in your imports.

Also:

- add a __init__.py file in `tests` directory
- in fileTest.py, you should have:

```py
import pytest
from src.module.file import func
```

Then, make sure the current working directory is the parent directory of `src` and run `pytest .`